# Angular + media stream

Tags: angular, stream

Tenho um componente onde solicito permissão para o usuário para utilizar a webcam, o intuito do mesmo é fazer o reconhecimento facial.

Está funcionando, porém quando navego para outros componentes, na aba do browser diz que a página está "usando a câmera ou microfone".

Isso é ruim pois gera uma desconfiança por parte dos usuários, pois estão em um componente onde a câmera/microfone não deveriam ser usados.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de parar a captura do vídeo ao mudar de componente, ou se precisa desautorizar, não sei ao certo, mas ao mudar de componente a webcam deveria parar de ser utilizada.

Obrigado!

Comment: cara, eu imagino que dê pra fazer algo com event listeners tipo assim:
https://juristr.com/blog/2016/09/ng2-event-registration-document/
você poderia usar o evento document.hasFocus() pra saber se mudou de janela e ai desativar

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo, consegui resolver da seguinte forma:
Usando o ciclo "ngOnDestroy()", criei uma função chamada "async destroyThing()", apenas para teste, e nela peguei o stream e usei o foreach para limpar qualquer stream existente.

const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(window.webkitURL.constraints);
    stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());

Dessa forma quando eu entro na tela ele faz uso da camera e quando sai ele para de usar.

Answer (score 0):

Para quem estiver enfrentando o mesmo problema, tente da seguinte forma:
No evento "ngOnDestroy", crie uma função auxiliar do tipo assíncrona, inicie o stream, e logo em seguida limpe qualquer stream existente.

async funcao(){
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(window.webkitURL.constraints);
stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
}